# Android Developer Tools: exclude asset files (php) from apk build

Tags: cordova, build, apk, adt, assets

I've a mobile website from which I build a phonegap app for android.

Unter `assets\www` I've put the website files that also includes some server side PHP scripts.

That works pretty well. My question is, how can I exclude the php files when building an apk?

I already tried to put this in my `build.xml`, but without any effect:

`<property name="aapt.ignore.assets" value="foo.php" />`

Thanks in advance for any kind of help.

Answer (score 0):

This **excludes** the whole `./www/app` directory **from the .apk** build:

`<property name="aapt.ignore.assets" value="&lt;dir&gt;app:" />`

Please see this link for more info: https://coderwall.com/p/ogxpdg